# ActiveRecord Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, chartkick

Hi am I'm just working on ActiveRecord for Chartkick as I'm still learning

at the moment 
I wrote code for reservation chart

```
<%= column_chart Reservation.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status => 2).group(:tool_id).sum(:total) %>
```

it displays fine

[image]

however, the red highlight is right but I want this ":tool_id" to change to more text like as "resrvation.tool_id" are the relationship to the "tool.brand"

when i wrote data table and it correct display

```
          <td><%= link_to reservation.tool.id, reservation.tool, target: :_blank %></td>
          <td><%= reservation.tool.brand %></td>
```

[image]

so I wonder how to tweak tell this chart as a group(:tool_id)change to tool.brand

Comment: `Reservation.joins(:tools).where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status => 2).group('tools.name').sum('reservations.total)` ?

Comment: perfect and it show correct, thank you and you should put it on answer your question,  I can upvote and correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Reservation.joins(:tools)
           .where(user_id: current_user.id, status: 2)
           .group('tools.brand')
           .sum('reservations.total)
```

This will group on the name instead of the id so that way you can get a count of all the tools with the same name :D

Comment: <%= column_chart Reservation.joins(:tool).where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status => 2).group('tools.brand').sum('reservations.total') %>